# ckeditor using ajax the editor does not load

Tags: php, ajax, ckeditor

I am using ajax to fill a form that has a textarea in it that I would like to be using ckeditor with. 
When the content is return the textarea gets created but the editor does not get applied to it. In my ajax file I have:
    `$initialValue = $thisjobrow['description'];`
    `$CKEditor = new CKEditor();`
    `$CKEditor->basePath = '../ckeditor/';`
    `$CKEditor->editor("myeditor1", $initialValue);`

at the top I have:
 include_once("../ckeditor/ckeditor.php") ;
so the textarea gets created my content gets added in but all I end up with is a plain old text area called myeditor1.

Any and all help most welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

When receiving the ajax response try to initialize ckeditor on page load (the page you call through ajax) or try with .live()

Comment: Thank you I think you are saying the same thing Steve_c, above, said but I am not sure. Could you expand your response please.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably are initializing the editor when your page is rendered.

You most likely want to initialize the editor in the callback of your AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am new at this so I am not clear on how to do this.

Comment: Here is my ajax call: function a_populatejob()
{
 var selectedoption = document.getElementById("jobselect");
 var jobid=selectedoption.options[selectedoption.selectedIndex].value;
 xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
 var url="ajax/ajaxeditjob.php";
   url=url+"?jobid="+jobid;
   xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
   xmlHttp.send(null);
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=jobform;
}

function jobform()
{
 if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
 {
  document.getElementById("jobpostingdiv").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
 }
}

Comment: Inside the if statement that checks for readyState complete you want to call your ckeditor initialization code.

Comment: Just to be more specific, you will need to call the initialization code in JavaScript, not using the PHP wrapper. See http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration